Interpreting this spacetime diagram involving two accelerating observers
I was studying this notes about Rindler coordinates and I have trouble making sense of this spacetime diagram (I labelled some points for convenience):


According to the inertia observer, when $t=0.521 c/g$, the wristwatch times of both leading and trailing accelerating observers will read $\bar{t}=\bar{\bar{t}}=0.5 c/g$, right?

I don't get what "Surfaces of constant $\bar{\bar{t}}$ are consistently in the past of surface of constant $\bar{t}$, meaning that a particular value of $\bar{\bar{t}}$ has already happened by the time $\bar{t}$ reaches that value" means. So when the trailing accelerating observer's wristwatch time reads $\bar{t}=0.5 c/g$, he is located at point A on the diagram. I am not sure when and where he will see the leading accelerating observer. It is either C or D. Similarly, when the leading accelerating observer's wristwatch time reads $\bar{\bar t}=0.5 c/g$, he is located at C. According to him, where the trailing observer is located? A or B?


Also, I wonder if the value of proper time is agreed by observers in different reference frames? In the diagram above, the inertial observer will read the same proper time from both accelerating observers: $\bar{t}=\bar{\bar t}$. But it seems like according to the trailing observer, $\bar{t}<\bar{\bar t}$ and according to the leading observer, $\bar{t}>\bar{\bar t}$. This is bit counter-intuitive to me. I expected $\bar{t}=\bar{\bar t}$ to hold to both accelerating observers.


Yes.

D and B. You can figure this out because $\bar{\bar{t}}$ is a surface of constant time for the trailing observer in the instanteous reference frame when the observer is at A, so events along that line/surface will be at the same time for them. That line intersects the leading observer at point D. Similar argument to figure out that the trailing observer is at B when the leading observer is at C.



I wonder if the value of proper time is agreed by observers in different reference frames?

It is.
For the rest of your paragraph, the key thing is that observers will agree about the proper time of some observer at a particular event (or point in your spacetime diagram). If you start asking things like "at the same time when observer A's proper time is X, what is observer B's proper time doing" then that will become observer dependent because it depends on what constant time surfaces you are using.
In other words, the numbers on an observer's wristwatch at a given spacetime point are an observable that all observers agree on. Comparing wristwatches between spacelike separated observers simultaneously will depend on the reference frame you are using to define surfaces of constant time.

OK, I don't do "bars", I do primes. So $S$, $S'$, $S''$ are the forever frame of initial rest-frame, and the primes are the instantaneous frames of the accelerating rockets (trailing and leading, respectively).
Note that these are these frames are exactly the frames described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_spaceship_paradox.
The rockets have simultaneous acceleration and fixed separation in $S$. Meanwhile, $S'$ and $S''$ each see the other rocket moving farther away.
The Minkowski diagram you included completely describes the paradox and its resolution.
Now if you imagine the two rockets exist in an imaginary elevator (only because a real elevator will Lorentz contract), then they are in a uniform gravitational field, and $S'$ is at a lower gravitational potential, so its clock runs slower, thus: it cannot keep up with $S''$. That rocket it further along in its acceleration profile and appears to pull away from $S'$.
Note also, that the instantaneous time coordinate axises, $t'$ and $t''$ are always tangent to their respective world-lines, and the $\bar t$ and $\bar{\bar t}$ represent the instantaneous spatial axises $x'$ and $x''$ at $A$ and $C$, respectively.
